# Using Split to separate a data string

Tags: split, postman

I'm using Postman to test an API call and part of the output includes a set of dates eg. Item 1, 01/01/2021, 01/08/2021 etc.

I want to get this data in a list html format in the visualizer such that I get Item 1 01/01/2021, Item 1 01/08/2021 etc.  I'm trying to use the Split function to do this but the call then fails - I'm guessing it's a syntax error but can't find any relevant advice.  Any help gratefully received.

the script that is working is:

```
    {{#each response.timetable}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{EventId}}</td>
            <td>{{Dates}}</td>
            <td>{{DayName}}</td>
            <td>{{StartTime}}</td>
            <td>{{FinishTime}}</td>

    {{#each Lecturers}}
        <td>{{LecturerName}}</td>
    {{/each}}

     {{#each Rooms}}
        <td>{{RoomName}}</td>
    {{/each}}

        </tr>
    {{/each}}

</table>
```

So I need to work out how to use the split command and where to incorporate this.

many thanks

Comment: where are you using the split function

Comment: Can you also provide an example of the response body, the template is void of context without that.

Comment: Yes a sample of the body is:
    "status": "passed",
    "timetable": [
        {
            "EventId": 845543,
            "SetId": "2019",
            "Dates": "30/09/2019, 07/10/2019, 14/10/2019",  
The final line contains a list of dates all for the same eventid - so what I want to produce is ID|Date, ID|Date etc

Comment: I've tried adding the split function in various places of the Test script

Answer (score 0):

```
tmplate = `     <table>
         <tr>
            <th>EventId</th>
            <th>Date</th>
         </tr>
         {{#each data}}
         <tr>
            <td>{{this.EventId}}</td>
            <td>{{this.Date}}</td>
         </tr>
         {{/each}}
      </table>
 

`



response = { "status": "passed", "timetable": [{ "EventId": 845543, "SetId": "2019", "Dates": "30/09/2019, 07/10/2019, 14/10/2019" }] }

let tmplist = []
response.timetable.forEach((val) => {

    EventId = val.EventId;
    Dates = val.Dates.split(',')

    Dates.forEach((date) => {
        let tmpobj = {}
        tmpobj.EventId = EventId
        tmpobj.Date = date
        tmplist.push(tmpobj)
    })


})

console.info(tmplist)


pm.visualizer.set(tmplate,{data:tmplist})
```

An example on how to create a table with the dates ,

store it to a list of object with key as eventid and date as value

**Output:**

[image]